# Angular child routes getting encoded

Tags: angular, parameters, routes

Cannot find an applicable example that works anywhere of child component routing used AFTER a parameter:

Right now `profile/userName` works but the children don't

```
{ path: 'profile/:userName', component: ProfileComponent, 
    children: [
        { path: 'deets', component: DeetsComponent }
    ]
},
```

I get 
`Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'profile/admin%40admin.com/%5B'deets'%5D'`

Not sure if it's the encoding in the URL or something I'm doing wrong with my routing that's causing the error?

Using Angular 4.1

Answer (score 0):

'profile/admin%40admin.com/%5B'reviews'%5D' url contains special characters that got encoded that they do nit match the route's path defined.

See w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: Do you know why the encoding could be happening? `%5D` is a closing bracket!

Comment: It's literally an empty component. I'm just working on creating a foundation for a project.

Answer (score 0):

i simply used this to get things working on angular 4.4; @angular/cli 1.4.5; node 6.11.3;

```
<a routerLink="/detail/{{item.id}}" routerLinkActive="active"> DETAIL </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are probably passing an input to a routerLink property but you aren't wrapping the input property in square brackets.

So `routerLink=` vs `[routerLink]=`. If you don't include the square brackets then the link will be treated as a string and you will see those encoding errors when you attempt to navigate to the route.

```
 <a [routerLink]="['detail', item.id, 'deets']">DETAIL</a>
```